# How to direct to an .aspx web form from a controller (MVC 5 framework)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, redirect

I have a MVC project which needs to incorporate SSRS reports as a part of the application. I've not done this before so I read up a couple of blogs, msdn pages etc. But I haven't come across a concrete solution yet.

Here's my code for the controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AppName.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
    //
    // GET: /Reports/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var reportParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        reportParameters.Add("First_Name", "TEST");

        Session["reportParameters"] = reportParameters;

        return Redirect("../Views/Reports/Index.aspx");
    }
}
}
```

The last line 'return Redirect' does not redirect to the desired page , instead it gives me a 'can't find the page' error and the link displayed is as follows:

"/localhost:port#/Error/PageNotFound?aspxerrorpath=/Views/Reports/Index.aspx"

I have even tried 'RedirectRoute' and 'RedirectToAction', but none of them work. I am using a web form instead of an MVC view because that's what is presribed by many SSRS tutorials in order to achieve what I want. I know the redirect line has worked in the past for most folks. I'm surely missing something here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
H

Comment: Did you try accessing the aspx page directly from browser? If you can see your page,then, is that url same as that of the relative url suggested by @JotaBe ?

Comment: I can't access the page from the browser and I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Are you able to run any other asp.net webforms app (at least some sample application) on the same box? Also do you have any IgnoreRoutes specified. If yes then you may need to take a dig at it.

Comment: This is my first .aspx web form for this project. I was successful in displaying the page using routing but that does not serve my purpose. I need to use a controller.

Comment: Did you try : return Redirect("/Views/Reports/Index.aspx"); ?

Comment: Yup I did try that as well. @JotaBe has found the fix. Apparently the web form needs to be outside the Views folder to be accessed (mentioned below).

Comment: @hrshd I've updated my answer to explain why you couldn't acces the .aspx page. If this worked for you, please, accept the answer.

Comment: Based on @JotaBe edit and set value to true as shown below, in web.config under views folder in the section: <appSettings><add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" /></appSettings>

Comment: @SivaGopal look at my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is just a little tweak to have it working: instead of using a relative URL, do use an URL relative to the application root `~`, like this:

```
return Redirect("~/Views/Reports/Index.aspx");
```

This will generate the current redirect URL.

**EDIT**

There can be a second problem in this case. The `Views` folder is somewhat special, because it has its own `web.config` which can make it impossible to get the files inside it. So you also need to move your `.aspx` page to somewhere else and update the `Redirect` accordingly.

To be more precise, if you look inside the `web.config` of your `Views` folder you'll find this:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  </httpHandlers>
```

which means that any request to this folder will be handled with the HttpNotFoundHandler, thus you'll get the "not found" message.

Comment: I have tried that as well, did not change the result!

Comment: Can you access the .aspx file using any URL? This should work without problem (I have it working like this). How does your URL look like when you use the ~? The only problem can have to do with some .config configuration. Can you make a simple .aspx page work?

Comment: This is the first .aspx file in my project and the page has no content but a 'Hello World' in it. I cannot access it through any link. The URL remains the same as mentioned above. I tried routing it to the page using routes.MapPageRoute in the RouteConfig file and that shows the page. But it bypasses the Controller methods altogether which is undesired.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't depend on routes. It must have something to do with the web.config. Are you using VS 2013? How did you add the .aspx page? With One ASP.NET it's easier to have MVC / web forms working side by side.

Comment: I am using VS 2013. I added the .aspx page by right clicking on the Reports folder -> add -> web form. What should I look for in the web.config file?

Comment: Move your .aspx out of the `Views` folder and try again

Comment: It works if it is outside the Views folder!!! That's a good start. So does that mean I'll have to create all my web forms outside my 'Views' folder?

Comment: To keep things rolling and better separation of concerns, you can create a separate folder directly under project and keep your webforms there. Still it should work.

Comment: @hrshd I've explained what's going on in an update to my answer.